# How to hint C# runtime that myclass is using X amount of unmanaged memory

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, unmanaged

To let it call myclass destructor or its IDisposable release method?

```
class MyClass:IDisposable
{
     [dllimport(..)]
     public static extern IntPtr allocate(...);

     public MyClass()
     {
          allocate();
     }

     ~MyClass()
     {
         Dispose();
     }
}
```

where a client developer doesn't care (or doesn't remember) about using myclass as

```
    using(MyClass foo = new MyClass())
    {


    }
```

but uses just like

```
   MyClass bar = new MyClass();
```

without any memory control designs in a method. So I need a guaranteed way(or at least hint) of telling garbage collector that it may call the destructor of `MyClass` or call `Dispose` method immediately after scope is exited(or just when memory gets fragmented enough) with the help of hint.

Is there any kind of hint applicable by these

- Attribute:

just like adding struct layout bu different

```
[MemoryAttribute.Uses10MBUnmanaged]
class MyClass {}
```

- Garbage collector:

I don't know how to relate garbage collection with class instances

```
GC.AddMemoryPressure(10*1024*1024) in MyClass constructor 
// but this is not per instance related. 
// GC still doesn't know which class is making what percentage of
// pressure(or does it?)
```

- Marshal.AllocHGlobal instead of `allocate()` from "C" space

Then, when developer creates hundreds of `MyClass` instances and when memory gets full, the runtime starts disposing out-of-scope instances accordingly with their unmanaged(`Marshal.AllocHGlobal`)+managed(`new float[1000]`) memory usages instead of just managed usage.

---

Maybe garbage collector learns in run-time when it collects/finalizes certain amount of instances(and watches total RAM consumed) and picks necessary ordering between objects that have unmanaged memory allocations?